# Charging time of lithium ion batteries

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging, charger

I am charging a 430mAh lithium polymer battery at 1C using [**BQ24232 charger IC**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24230.pdf)  (from Texas instruments). The charge terminates within 1 hour 20 min with battery voltage showing 4.17V. On research I came to know that it would take a little more than 2 hours to complete the charge cycle when charged at 1C.

Why does my battery charges so quickly at 1C?

[image]

Comment: 1C = full charge/discharge in 1 hour. Where did your estimate of 2 hours come from?

Comment: And why would it take more than 2 hours?

Comment: 80 mins charging time for the battery of that size is perfectly normal.

Comment: @Cheibriados, I believe 1C means the charge current is 1 times the battery capacity.  For example, the 1C charge current of a 2000mAh battery is 2 amps.  The 0.5C charge current of a 3000mAh battery is 1.5 amps.

Comment: @st2000, you are correct w/r/t C-rate, but my point is the same; 2 hours seems arbitrary and without knowing where it comes from, the question is nebulous.

Comment: Understood.  W.r.t. the 2 hours:  The EOC (End Of Charge) can vary so much that putting an exact time on it is not very useful.  The TI.COM chip may be counting coulomb,  checking cell temperature or looking for a dip in voltage or current.  These tests likely vary due to many things such as the age of the cell.   I'm thinking as long as the time is reasonable its ok.

Comment: @Cheibriados,i have attached an image showing the charge time for 0.5C and 1C charge rate of a 1000mah battery,sorry the image is little vague,couldn't find a better one..you could see from the graph that 1C charge rate takes more than 2 hours to complete charging

Comment: You are right that a full charge at 1C will take longer than 1 hour due to the CV stage. But 2 hours is excessive, and if the battery is not fully discharged, it will potentially take less than 1 hour.

Comment: Many of the comments are wrong or misleading. A LiPO cell is usually charged initially in CC mode at C/1 rate. ie 1.4A for a 1400 mAh cell. When charging at C/1 the battery accepts 1/60th of I capacity per minute. At some point voltage reaches Vmax and charhinbg changes to CV mode. Current falls controlled by battery chemistry at constant voltage. CC to CV transition is typeicallt at 70% - 80% of full charge. SO if CC-CV occurs at 80% charge the transition will occur at 48 minutes = 80% of 1 hour. The current now falls under battery control and this MAY take say 2 hours more to complete. !

Answer (score 3):

Your cell is not charging more quickly than normal. Rather, the other battery in your graph is charging much more slowly than normal because it has high internal resistance so quickly reaches the CV = Constant Voltage phase, which means that the charge time will increase because more time is spent in the CV phase (at lower charge current).

Below is typical CC,CV charge for a similar capacity cell. Notice that the charge completes in 73 mins - close to the 80 mins of your 430mAh cell. Notice also that it stays in CC = Constant Current mode for 57 of 73 mins, about 79% of the charge, which is typical for a healthy cell.

[image]

Contrast that to the graph you supplied below, where the 1C charge quickly enters CV in about 12 mins of a 141 min charge, i.e. at about the 9% time mark. This is typical of a very unhealth cell with very high internal resistance.

[image]

The first graph is from the site lygte-info.dk, which has a large number of [reviews of batteries and chargers](http://www.lygte-info.dk/info/indexBatteriesAndChargers%20UK.html). Perusing some of those should give you better intuition on typical (dis)charge curves.

Answer (score 0):

Battery charging is seldom considered an exact procedure.  There are acceptable procedures to charge different battery chemistries.  But in practice there can be many subtle variations.  Consider your TI.COM chip.  There are likely many internal registers designed to give the OEM developer a way to adapt the chip to the application. For example, the application may demand a quick charge time (i.e. 1C or more) in exchange for shorter secondary battery life.  Or the application may be for a device which routinely connect to mains power.  As mains is expected to be normally available, the charge time can be extended (i.e. 1C or less) thereby extending secondary battery life.

[This](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries) is a good place to start to learn more.